# How to get rid of JSONException: No value for success?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I have no idea what am I doing wrong. I have made a registration form which takes a unique code which I save in sql database so when the user enters wrong code I want the error message or toast to appear.
Right now I am facing org.json JSONException: No value for success.

How can I set error message to the code textview which is defined in mainActivity?
or how can I make the toast appear.

Is there any better way to restrict users from signing up rather than what I am currently using (manually saving the unique code in a database)?

register.php

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] =="POST"){

    require_once 'connect.php';

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $code=$_POST["code"];

    //for checking if the email address already exists
    $mysql_select="SELECT email FROM register_table where email ='$email' ";

    $res=mysqli_query($conn,$mysql_select);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0 ) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

        if($email==$row['email']){
            echo "Email already exists";
        }
    }else {
       $code_query="SELECT code FROM code_table where code='$code' ";
       $code_result=mysqli_query($conn,$code_query);
       $roww = mysqli_fetch_assoc($code_result);

       $sql="INSERT INTO register_table (name, email,password) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$password')";

       if($code!=$roww['code']){

           $resultt["codes"] = "0";
           echo json_encode($resultt);

           $result["success"] = "0";
           echo json_encode($result);

           mysqli_close($conn);

       }else if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql) && $code==$roww['code'] ){

        $resultt["codes"] = "1";
        echo json_encode($resultt);

        $result["success"] = "1";
        echo json_encode($result);

        mysqli_close($conn);

    }else {
       $result["success"] = "0";
       $result["message"] = "error";

       echo json_encode($result);
       echo "registration not successful";
       mysqli_close($conn);
   }
}

}else{
    echo "register method is not post";
}

?>
```

The rest of the code is perfectly running, the below method belongs to AsyncTask class

BackgroundTask.java

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String res) {

        try {
            JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(res);
            String success = jsonobject.getString("success");
            String code_result=jsonobject.getString("codes");

            if(code_result.equals("0") && success.equals("0")){
                Toast.makeText(context,"Please enter the correct code",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if (success.equals("1") && code_result.equals("1")) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Register Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Register Error!" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

Comment: You really should find a better PHP tutorial. I recommend looking at https://phpdelusions.net/

Answer (score 0):

**JSONObject.getString()** method does not return **null** when the input key was not found in the object, and will throw a JSONException.

Use [optString()](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optString(java.lang.String)):

```
String success = jsonobject.optString("success");
String code_result = jsonobject.optString("codes");
if (success != null && code_result != null) {
      // ...
}
```

Comment: Can you tell a bit more what is not working? You still get the same JSONException?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using echo multiple times, also you should only use echo for json encoded data..

To get the problem just try to use postman for getting API response for different scenarios, you will understand the issue..